# Django HiddenInput Security against User changing POST data

Tags: django, forms, model, modelform

As far as I know it is quite a burden to create a form that is safe and required an extra related field.

Example how I do this:
1. Create form.

```
class Myform(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    relatedfieldinstance = kwargs.pop('relatedfield')
    super(CustomActivityTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        

    self.fields['relatedfield '].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
    self.fields['relatedfield '].instance = relatedfieldinstance

THIS STILL ENABLES THE USER TO HIJACK YOUR POST!!!
```

2. create view:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None, instance=None, relatedfield =relatedfield ) 
if form.is_valid:

     mynewinstance=form.save(commit=False)

      mynewinstance.relatedfield = relatedfield 
      mynewinstance.save()
```

Is there no better way to this? As it is easy to forget to set it again in the form.is_valid clause and think it is working (IT IS!), and thereby creating a huge security loophole.

And I need the relatedfield, because it is necessary for my model validation (clean methods on the model).

Comment: Why to have a hidden input if you nevertheless set the field in your view? I'd drop that field completely and use the view's part of your code.

Comment: As explained that is not possible, because I need to do form validation with that field.